# Using templates and vars_prompt, conflicting action statements

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am using ansible templates to create a file in which I need a variable introduced through prompt so I try to do the following:

```
- name: task1
     template:
        src: template.yaml.j2
        dest: ~/mypath/file.yaml
        owner: ubuntu
        group: ubuntu
        mode: 0644
     vars_prompt:
        - name: myvariable
          prompt: "Introduce your variable"
          private: yes
```

That code fragment is written in the /tasks/main.yml file inside an ansible role

When I execute the main playbook I get the following error:

**ERROR! conflicting action statements: template, vars_prompt**

Maybe that options are not compatbile but I tried to include a single var without prompt (using `vars` instead of `vars_prompt`) and it's working correctly

Is there any options to use the prompt var for templates??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vars_prompt` is a [keyword of the play](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#play), i.e. it must be placed in the playbook, on the same level as `hosts`, `tasks` or `roles`.

Later you can access and use the varaible filled by user input.
*In your example, the data entered by the user is then in the variable `myvariable`, so you can use it with `"{{ myvariable }}"` for example.*

`vars_prompt` must not be defined inside a task.

More about [`vars_prompt` and interactive input](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) in the Ansible Docs.

Comment: Working! Thank you very much, it was much easier than I thought, I was misunderstanding the documentation and how to use it, so my fault